# A little query between href and iframe tag

Tags: javascript, html

So yesterday i submitted a sample website to my teacher and she spoke in a real condescending manner and asked me to replace the href tag with the iframe tag, when i told her they both have different usage she asked me to shut up and use the iframe tag to link my webpages together. I have no clue how to do that please do help. Is it possible to replace href with iframe?? if yes how can it be done?
All help is appreciated.

Comment: No, it is not possible, since `href` is not a tag, it is an attribute.

Comment: isn't iframe deprecated?

Comment: You may want to clarify what is the goal of the project first to your teacher

Comment: @Prajwal [Nope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: Coding teaching in India is really substandard, she told us to make a website on any topic.

Comment: Might be there is some confession between you and your teacher. You should better ask her again.

Comment: @kartikey Gaur you can also provide this link yo your teacher
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, now I can stand my ground.

Comment: @HardenRahul You mean "confusion" ..?

Comment: Yes I mean that and sry for my type mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how most HTML designers would describe the two tag types:

An iFrame is HTML that pulls a "raw" search form into a window within a page. The iFrame is still considered a link by search engines, but the content appears to be displayed on the website itself.
A link sends visitors to a page that displays the form content, while embedding the navigation, sidebar, and footer of the primary website. 
What do these two HTML tags look like?

An iFrame tag looks something like this:

```
<iframe src="myIDXformpage.php" height="300" width="100%"> </iframe>
```

A link looks like this:

```
<a href="myIDXformpage.php">MLS Search</a>
```